# Higher Refresh Rate not working - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, gnome, display

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and tried to configure a higher refresh rate than 60Hz.

Everything worked fine, the higher refresh rate was detected, and I was able to configure it. However, only the mouse is at 165Hz. The rest seems to be stuck at 60Hz. I attempted to fix this using CompizConfig Settings Manager, but that did not help.

I can confirm that this is not a hardware issue as Fedora34 works fine on the higher refresh rate.

Other threads seem to indicate that this is an issue with gnome. I was able to find these two bug reports:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meta-gnome3/+bug/1767693
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1763892

I couldn't find any more information on this.
Is this supposed to be solved with Ubuntu 20.04? Are there any fixes or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue with this by switching from the open-sourced driver to the proprietary driver. Unfortunately, right now the proprietary driver is a little buggy in some full-screen applications. Maybe it will work for you